# Developing NEST client for UI that has no web browser/web view

Tags: nest-api

I'm looking hard into developing a client for a control system, but I'm fairly sure that the authorization process on the client requires a web-view/browser interaction where the user can authorize their devices, etc.  My particular UIs may not have a web view/browser available on them.

Will a web view/browser be required?  Can a user authorize a client from the "outside" somehow?

Diving into the authorization docs for the fourth time...  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PIN authentication if the device doesn't have a web browser.

The third section of this page (https://developer.nest.com/documentation/authorization-overview) addresses that.

[image: https://s3.amazonaws.com/support-assets.nest.com/web_developer/ext/pin-auth-flow-detailed.png]

Comment: Thank you.  I read through this and the previous page at least five times.  I kept missing the line: "PIN-based authorization is generally used for devices with no web UI, and that have a numeric keypad interface."  I'd give you a +, but alas, I'm still too new here...

Comment: FYI, the pin doesn't seem to be purely numeric. At least, it hasn't in my testing. Are you able to accept the answer? I haven't asked many questions here either.

Comment: Non-Numeric isn't a problem either.  I have a GUI, and can present a keyboard.  I see the checkmark now.  I'm still learning this SO thing I've been using for years!